# PHP skip undefined offset in foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach, skip, notice

I'm trying to scan hundreds of folders each containing an excel file.

Here's the simplified workflow

- scan folders in loop
- get first folder name and run it trough some regex (to get some info from the name)
- open the folder and open the excel file inside
- scan excel file for info's (with PHPExcel)
- save everything to Database

Ok so all this is working just fine, except when i run into an excel file which is corrupted.

The problem then is that the PHPEXCEL library cant read it and it throughs back a "Notice: Undefined offset:" and this breaks my **foreach** loop.

**So here is what I'm looking for:** *a way to somehow skip or something the erros and notices and continue with the next folder and file*.

Is there a way?
Thank's for any help.

Ok so here is the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($inputFileName as $key => $fileName) {
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);

$activeSheet = $objReader->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,false,true,false);

echo "<pre>";
    echo $key;
echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the phpexcel library.

Comment: Maybe a `try`/`catch` can handle the error.

Comment: @Barmar You can't catch notice, only exceptions.

Comment: If these are just notices, just lower the error reporting setting.

Comment: @Barmar i lowered the error reporting, no more notice but the loop stops. Already tried Try / catch, didn't work

Comment: Are you checking for a null or undefined value being returned by the library? If you don't show your code, we can only guess at what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: @cbuckley maybe it's a bug, thought about that, but to tell you the truth i don't know where to even start to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar i updated the question with the code

Comment: @cbuckley fallowing your idea i went to the phpexcel library and solved the problem there. So thank you.

Comment: @MrSam https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

```
foreach ($inputFileName as $key => $fileName) {
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);

    if ($objReader) {
        $activeSheet = $objReader->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,false,true,false);

        echo "<pre>";
            echo $key;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

It's pretty common for functions to return `false` when they fail.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, but it kind of gave me a direction, i didn't wanted to do this but now i think my only solution is to `hack` the PHPEXCEL library, to give some result if it cant open an excel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the function error_reporting at the beginning of your script to skip notices :

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

And set it back to your original value once you are done with your treatment :

```
error_reporting(-1); //Report all errors
```

You can find more info here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: like i told @Barmar i tried that but the loop still stops, without notice

Comment: @Mr.Sam just do `error_reporing(0)` at the top of the script, then